# SharePoint Apps Icon missing

Tags: sharepoint-addin, custom-application

I have configured SharePoint apps correctly and I only want to add free apps available in SP Store. However, when I add free apps, it gets added but when I click on apps (in Site Contents), the icons are not visible in the page and the page is not structured. My account has internet access during this process. Do I need any other permissions to access these apps correctly.

Edit: My Web Application is configured with Kerberos. Do I need to configured Kerberos to App Domain URL also?

[image]

Comment: Is this issue for all Apps or a specific app ?

Comment: @M.Qassas, Its for all apps.

Comment: Finally, I solved the issue by creating a listener web application and making changes in its IIS Binding and redirecting it to HTTPS protocol. I am not much convenience of creating this listener web application for apps but its required. Bloggers writes that app domain will use it  internally.

Comment: Great Job!. Please add your solution as a detailed answer to be helpful for all future visitors